# Accessing client side IP address in ASP.NET Core

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, webapi

Hope you all are fine.
I'm working on a project that based on vue-js (FRONTEND) and .net core web api (BACKEND).

The issue I'm facing is I've to get the client IP-ADDRESS using that C# dll which is located in Server. I don't know how to get it.

Please let me know if any of you know.

Will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The requester's IP address can be found on the `Connection` value of the `HttpContext` for the request, as [`RemoteIpAddress`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.connectioninfo.remoteipaddress?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_ConnectionInfo_RemoteIpAddress). For example, in an ASP.NET Core controller action:

```
public IActionResult MyAction()
{
    IPAddress? ipAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;

    return Ok();
}
```

As noted in docs, this might be null.

Comment: Will it be client side IP-ADDRESS ?

Comment: It will be the IP address of the requester seen by the server. This would be the client's IP in the case it isn't masked by a proxy or something else.

Comment: OK let me implement it,
Then I'll let you know.